# Azure Devops build custom conditions -target previous build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to target the previous build in a custom condition?

What I try to accomplish:

1. Post a message to Slack when build fails (this is easy)
2. Post a message to Slack when a build changes status from failed to success (I don't want all successful builds posted to Slack, only the first one after a failed build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not able to target the previous build in a custom condition. Custom condition can only target in the same build. You can add a task to use REST API checking the previous build result and current build result, and determine whether to post a message to Slack.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to retrieve the latest build and read the build status using the Rest API.  The Slack message would then be conditional on previous BuildResult == succeeded & current BuildResult == failed.

You can get information about the previous build using the azure-devops rest API here:

[Azure DevOps Services Rest API GET Builds List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: Thanks, will consider this approach if it's not possible directly in a build task